# How to add entries to a JSON array/list

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to set up a Discord bot that only lets people on a list in a JSON file use it, I am wondering how to add data to the JSON array/list but I'm not sure how to move forward and I have had no real luck looking for answers elsewhere.

This is an example of how the JSON file looks:

```
{
    IDs: [
    "2359835092385",
    "4634637576835",
    "3454574836835"
    ]
}
```

Now, what I am looking to do, is add a new ID to "IDs" and not have it completely break, and I wish to be able to have other entries in the JSON file as well so i can make something like "AdminIDs" for people that can do more stuff to the bot.

Yes. I know I can do this stuff role based in guilds/servers, but I would like to be able to use the bot in DMs as well as on guilds/server.

What I want/need is a short and simple to manipulate script that I can easily put in to a new command so I can add new people to the bot without having to open and edit the JSON file manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't parsed your data already via the package json then you can do the following for parsing the data:

```
import json
json_code = { "..": ... }
parsed_json = json.dumps(json_code)
print(parsed_json['IDs'])
```

Then you can simply use this data like a normal list and append data to it.

Answer (score 0):

All keys must be surrounded by a string
In this cause the key is the IDs while the value is the list and the value of the list would be the items inside it

```py
import json

data={
    "IDs":[
    "2359835092385",
    "4634637576835",
    "3454574836835"
    ]
}
```

Let's say that your JSON data is from a file, to load it so that you can manipulate it do the following

```py
raw_json_data=open('filename.json',encoding='utf-8')
j_data=json.load(raw_json_data) #Now j_data is basically the same as data except difference in name
print(j_data)
# >> {'IDs': ['2359835092385', '4634637576835', '3454574836835']}
```

To add things inside the list IDs you use the append method

```py
data['IDs'].append('adding something') #or j_data['IDs'].append("SOMEthing")
print(data)
# >> {'IDs': ['2359835092385', '4634637576835', '3454574836835', 'adding something']}
```

To add a new key

```py
data['Names']=['Jack','Nick','Alice','Nancy']
print(data)
# >> {'IDs': ['2359835092385', '4634637576835', '3454574836835', 'adding something'], 'Names': ['Jack', 'Nick', 'Alice', 'Nancy']}
```